# Putting quotes around a form value with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to pass this JavaScript variable:

```
var dateString =  $('input[name="date"]').val()  ;
```

On the JSON get code below:

```
$.getJSON('DisplayMap.php', {runDate1 : dateString},  function(data) {
  for (var i in data.b) {
    output.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data.b[i].Ya, data.b[i].Za));
  }
  alert(output);
});
```

It seems json will accept this : `{runDate1 : '2013-01-06'}`

But not when its pass through a variable like this `{runDate1 : dateString}`

Comment: I don't see any JSON in your code. `{runDate1 : dateString}` is an **object literal**. What exactly makes you think that it does not work? You already asked a couple of questions around this and the responses so far should have helped. If they didn't then you really have to explain what the problem is, otherwise you will get the the same answers every time.

Comment: You're building an object literal, which jQuery parses and passes as GET parameters to `DisplayMap.php`... no JSON in sight. You'll end up with `DisplayMap.php?runDate1=[dateString]`

Comment: You should check whether your variable is being resolved for what you expected it to. I'm sure there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @Motta when I do an alert (dateString); its showing my exactly what I want which is 2013-01-06. I've even tried adding the single quotes around but to no avail

Comment: Did you found the problem's solution?

Comment: Yes, the value of the form wasnt being passed initially. ive managed to fix it and it works fine now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var dateString =  $('input[name="date"]').val().toString();
```